# Location of code in a page

Tags: google-chrome, php, html, debug

I'm working with Google Chrome for debugging and a lot of times i cant remember where i initially implemented codes for different things...

I am looking for a php code that i inserted to one of my Wordpress files but i cant remember which.

Is there a way to find out a location of a selected code in 'Inspect Element'?

For example if i need to find out a CSS property, the debugger tells me which css and where it is..how can i do that for html codes and php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot see PHP code on the client side. When you request a PHP site from your server, the server translates your PHP code into whatever the PHP script outputs (e.g. through `echo` commands) and you'll just see that instead, or the HTML interleaved with PHP. You will never see the PHP source code.

To see the HTML code for a certain element, open the Inspector and click the loupe at the bottom.

[image]

Then, hover over the elements on the website you'd want to inspect and click them. The HTML source will be highlighted.